# How can I make a batch file wait a specified time between one command and the next in DOS 5.00?

Tags: ms-dos, dosbox

How can I make my batch file pause before executing the next command?
I found a few solutions, but none of them seem to work in DOS 5.00.

Thanks in advance for any help.

(By the way, I am using iDOS/DOSbox.)

Comment: Does it have to be DOS 5, or can it use DOS 6.22 (the last stand-alone release of MSDOS)? -- Nevermind, I see that DOSBox reports as version 5.0..